# PHP if-Statement with multiple conditions

Tags: php

How would the valid syntax be for the following if-statement?

```
if ($properties->offering_type === 'y' || $properties->offering_type === 'p' && $properties->sold != 'y') { 
  // echo something
} else {
}
```

I want to `echo something` when `offering_type` is either `y` or `p` and `sold` is not `y`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&&` has higher precedence than `||`, so your condition is interpreted as

```
if ($properties->offering_type === 'y' || 
    ($properties->offering_type === 'p' && $properties->sold != 'y')) {
```

You need to add parentheses to group the `||` together.

```
if (($properties->offering_type === 'y' || $properties->offering_type === 'p')
    && $properties->sold != 'y') {
```

Comment: A well explained answer:).

Comment: Indeed well explained!

Answer (score 1):

```php
<?php

if ( ($properties->offering_type === 'y' || $properties->offering_type === 'p') && ($properties->sold != 'y') ) { 
  // echo something
} 
else {

}
```

Please note that you are using `===` which means the type should also be the same. And you are not doing that for the `sold` property `(!=)`.